# C# (non-static) class to represent paths

Tags: c#, path, types

I'm looking for a C# class **that represents a file system path**. I would like to use it (instead of strings) as the data type of variables and method arguments (top reasons: type safety, concat-proof, logical comparisons).

- System.IO.Path provides most of the functionality I want, but it is static.
- System.IO.FileInfo, as I understand, performs IO operations to do its job. I only want a wrapper for the path string.

Thanks!

Comment: System.IO.Path is Static class and not abstract.

Comment: Someone recently wrote a framework like this, if I can find out what it's called I'll put it in an answer, until then start Googling for it. :)

Comment: Found that framework - FluentPath.  I've added an answer to that effect.

Comment: Oops, meant static indeed. I'm not sure why I wrote abstract (twice!).

Comment: I too was looking for this functionality, similar to working with a Java File object.  Wondering why they don't have something similar as core part of .NET?  You shouldn't have to use a 3rd party library or write your own wrapper to deal with this.  I'm just recently going from Java to a job working with C# and I would have thought C# would have been the more robust of the two for working with file I/O.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be the library [NDepend.Helpers.FileDirectoryPath](http://filedirectorypath.codeplex.com/) is what you are looking for.

It provides:

- Strongly typed File/Directory path.
- Relative / absolute path conversion.
- Path normalization API
- Path validity check API
- Path comparison API
- Path browsing API.
- Path rebasing API
- List of path operations (TryGetCommonRootDirectory, GetListOfUniqueDirsAndUniqueFileNames, list equality…)

Comment: I'll look into this one, it looks promising. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't end up using it because of time constraints (couldn't afford necessary refactoring). This library was, however, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Well, what you're *asking for* is [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx). But what you *want* to do (or more accurately, what you should do) is use System.Path and friends. It's what everyone else does, and it's what is correct and appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `System.IO.Path` is `static`, not `abstract`.

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you could either use `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`, `System.Uri`, or create a custom class that uses `System.IO.Path` internally.

Answer (score 1):

`System.IO.Path` is not an abstract class, it's a static class; the difference being that you can use the static `Path` methods to manipulate strings that represent file paths.

You can also use the `System.Uri` class for some of the file path operations, but that class really targets URLs, not files.

If you want to be fancy, or you need your file path manipulation methods to be attached to a specific instance, you can write a set of extension methods to the `String` class that perform file path operations using the `Path` methods internally.

Answer (score 0):

Build a wrapper for System.IO.Path and add the missing functionality to your wrapper.

Comment: Naturally I could do that, but I would like to avoid writing NIH code. It's a solved problem.